# How do I represent static constants that are derived at run time?

Tags: java, oop, guice, dropwizard

I have `senderA` and `senderB` both implementing `sender` and both singletons, and I have a `SenderWrapper` (which could possibly implement an `ISenderWrapper`) class where I want to represent `SenderA` and `SenderB` as some sort of static constants.

I'm getting the instances, `senderA` and `senderB` using `Guice` at runtime.

I'm creating many instances of the `SenderWrapper` class in runtime (think one per request) and I want to somehow represent `senderA` and `senderB` in these classes. I will be using them in some methods defined in `SenderWrapper`.

I have a couple of solutions to this:

1. I have two non static fields `senderA` and `senderB` and I pass them from the constructor. (Perhaps I could inject them as well but I'm worried about performance)
2. I can have *static* fields for `senderA` and `senderB` and set them up in runtime in a `Guice` module. But the problem is that these fields will not be const and sends the wrong message that it could be changed during runtime.

```
public class SenderWrapper implements ISenderWrapper {
    
    public static Sender senderA = null;
    public static Sender senderB = null;

    public void dummyMethod() {
        senderA.send(); senderB.send();
    }

}
    
//in Guice module
@Provides
public providesSenderA(){
    Sender senderA = new SenderA();
    SenderWrapper.senderA = senderA;
    return senderA;
}
```

3. My current solution is using an `Enum` class to represent `senderA` and `senderB`. Something like

```
enum Senders {
senderA, senderB
}
```

I get a feeling that this is similar to the solution mentioned in point 2, at least functionally. I just hate using enums though.

What is the best, most elegant way to go about this situation? I don't mind refactoring, some level of indirection to solve this.

Comment: Using enums - in general, not related to your question - is one of the best things you can do. In Java they're really powerful and easy-to-use with class-like abilities. And your IDE can generate lots of code for you and check for inconsistencies, which you would have to check for yourself using any other way.

Comment: I do not understand how solution 2 would work. Please clarify.

Comment: @JayC667 edited to provide example

Comment: Ok now I understand. You could use that, but you would HAVE to initialize it yourself or set some rules. I don't know Guice and thus cannot tell you how to properly dependency inject static fields. And FYI: I think the 'static' is more the problem for injection than 'final', because if you have `final X x;` you can 'always' set the x later via Reflection (mind caches and JVM implementations), so dependency injection frameworks/modules will make use of that.

Comment: If you already use guice the additional overhead is not a major concern (if in doubt, measure).  Consider having a single provider that returns a or b.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I have considered that but I have never seen this pattern and tbh it doesn't seem like a great idea to have Guice running _per request_. What do you think?

Comment: Provider gluing happens only once. Do the choosing yourself

Answer (score 0):

Why not have an Enum (renamed it a bit, so we know it's an enum, not a class) like this:

```
enum SenderType {
    SENDER_A, SENDER_B
}
```

And then have your class like this:

```
public abstract class SenderBase {

    public final SenderType myType;
    
    public SenderBase(SenderType pType) {
        myType = pType;
    }
    
    // optional getter
    public SenderType getType() {
        return myType;
    }
    
    public void send() {
        // here, send myType to socket. 
        // best is to send myType.name(), because ordinal WILL change when you re-order the enums in their enum class.

        // or, if you have different send() implementations for A and B, make this method abstract (and empty, remove body) so you FORCE A and B to implement it.
    }
    
}
```

and your class implementations like this:

```
class SenderA extends SenderBase { 
    public SenderA () {
        super(SenderType.SENDER_A);
    }
}

class SenderB extends SenderBase {
    public SenderB () {
        super(SenderType.SENDER_B);
    }
}
```

and construct via:

```
SenderA senderA = new SenderA();
SenderB senderB = new SenderB();
```

and your Wrapper:

```
public abstract class SenderWrapper {

    public final SenderA mySenderA;
    public final SenderB mySenderB;
    
    public SenderWrapper() {
        mySenderA = new SenderA();
        mySenderB = new SenderB();
    }
    
    public void send() {
        mySenderA.send();
        mySenderB.send();
    }
    
}
```

actually now that I think about the Wrapper, it might even have an (Array)List where you add all your implementations, and in `send()` just iterate over them.

Comment: I think you are forgetting the most important part of the puzzle, i.e ```SenderWrapper``` which has instances of ```senderA``` and ```senderB```. 


How do I represent that?

Comment: Updated my answer. Have to leave now for a trip, cannot answer until tomorrow at least.

Comment: The problem with this approach is, its not honouring the fact that ```senderA``` and ```senderB``` are singletons

Comment: Well, then implement your singleton strategy on top of it, it's really easy... theres multiple easy solutions that all easily fit with my approach.

Comment: No.. I don't think its simple to implement the singleton strategy on top of it. Could you suggest how to do it? You will end up listing one of my three existing solutions (which I dont want to use)

Answer (score 0):

The answer turned out to be anonymous class.

In my Guice module, I do this:

```
//in Guice module
@Provides
public providesSenderWrapper(final SenderA senderA, final SenderA, senderB){
    return new ISenderWrapper {

        @Override
        public Send() {
            senderA.send(); senderB.send();
        }
    }
}
```

Neat way to have effective constants in the class.